# Admob banner is not visible but does respond to click

Tags: android, admob

I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) official tutorial to set up AdMob in my app.

The ad banner is not visible, but if I click the bottom of the screen, the test ad will open and take me to the Google's AdMob page to give me more information.

This is the layout of my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentDrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/leftDrawer"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I know the ads will load correctly in *some* situations, but not this one. For instance, if I place the `AdView` as a direct child of the `DrawerLayout`, it will be visible and respond to clicks, but it will be centered directly in the middle of the screen. This is just an example, since I know `DrawerLayout` should only have two direct children: the drawer content and the main content.

Does anyone know why the ads are behaving this way? I'd appreciate any advice.

Thank you!

Edit: If I switch between `Fragment`s in my `Activity`, the ad sometimes shows for a brief moment. When it shows, it is in the correct spot and loaded correctly. I don't know why it seems to be hidden behind my `Fragment` but still responsive to click events.

Comment: is there any blank space at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @nayoso Not with this layout. However, if I nest both the `RelativeLayout` `fragmentDrawerContainer` and the `AdView` inside another `RelativeLayout`, and use the tag `layout_above="@+id/adView`, then there *will* be blank space in the size of an ad, but it will not respond to clicks.

Comment: Have you tried to use the standart size one (BANNER) instead of the smart size one (SMART_BANNER)?

Comment: @nayoso Yes, it behaves exactly the same way.

Comment: you add/replace fragment to `fragmentDrawerContainer`??

Comment: if you don't add/replace fragment to `fragmentContainer`, is `AdView` loaded correctly??

Comment: @calvinfly Yes. The `Fragment` is composed only of a custom `View` I wrote that overrides `onDraw()`. The `View` has `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to `match_parent`. If the `View` doesn't draw itself for whatever reason, the ad shows fine. But as soon as the `View` draws itself, it covers the ad.

Comment: `RelativeLayout`'s child views would cover other child view order by z-index. try to change the structure of `fragmentContainer`. `fragmentContainer` as a vertical `LinearLayout` with two child view, one is used to add fragment, another one is `AdView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @calvinfly, the problem was in the z-ordering of the layouts. Arranging in various structures of `RelativeLayout`s and `LinearLayout`s did not work, but for z-ordering cases, `FrameLayout` is ideal.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>

</FrameLayout>
```